# How to display attachment in force.com sites (In portal pages)

Tags: force.com-sites, attachment

I am trying display the attachment in force.com site (In my portal page), I have used the following code

```
<apex:page  showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false">
  <embed src="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, 'attachmentId')}" style="width:100%; height:950px;">
 </embed>  

 <!-- <apex:iframe src="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, 'attachmentId')}" height="200" />  -->
 <!-- {!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, 'attachmentId')} -->

</apex:page>
```

In the instance it displays attachment properly but in site it displays junk data.

Comment: What type of attachment it is?

Comment: Are you sure you need single quote for attachmentId ? I thought it should be {!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, attachmentId)} as per the document here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_action.htm

Comment: Here attachments consist of, image, text, word and excel files.

Comment: Karthik, I have used a hardcoded value there something like '0000000000'

Comment: You should do view source and see what is being send from server. the other think to check it access rights and permission.